# Why are created files not owned by the final owner after transferring Google Sheets ownership using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-drive-api

I've developed a google spreadsheet with associated apps script, which creates files in google drive. Manifest (appsscript.json has of course been updated accordingly).
When running script, created files are owned by me (obviously).
I developed this script for another entity, with its own Google account. So, when work was finalized, I changed the ownership of my spreadsheet to the "final" owner, and this owner accepted the ownership.
The point is that, when this user uses the spreadsheet and triggers files creation, the owner of created files is still... me.
I guess there is a reason which this behaviour is obvious, but can't figure what.

So my question is 2-folded:

1. Why ownership of created files doesn't follow the spreadsheet's ownership transfer, as "everyone (former and final) owner agreed to the process ?
2. Is there a way to have the script behave as wished => files created by script belong to the owner of the script ?

I can provide some extracts of script, but IMO this question is very high level so I don't know what to provide, except that I use `Folder.createFile(fileName, fileContent, mimeType)` function, and that appsscript.json is like:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
]
```

Many thanks for help,
Emmanuel

Here is details of what I did:

- Wrote spreadsheet/script on my own account
- Transfered property to final owner
- The owner uses the spreadsheet and triggers the function (checkbox+installable trigger)
- Expected: The files are created with the same ownership as the **owner** of the script
- Got: The files are created with the same ownership as the **developer** of the script

---

Saving function code:

```
function saveEntityIntoGDrivePDF(entitySheet) {
    const entitysBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const paramSheet = entitysBook.getSheetByName("Paramètres généraux");
    const entitysStorageFolderOnGDriveId = paramSheet.getRange('B30').getValue();
    const entitysStorageFolderOnGDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(entitysStorageFolderOnGDriveId);
    const authorizationToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    const exportLink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+entitysBook.getId()+"/export?format=pdf&size=a4&portrait=true&scale=4&top_margin=1.00&bottom_margin=1.00&left_margin=0.50&right_margin=0.50&gridlines=false&printnotes=false&pageorder=2&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&fzr=false&fzc=false&attachment=false&r1=0&r2=40&c1=1&c2=6&gid="+entitySheet.getSheetId();
    const year = entitySheet.getRange('J5').getValue();
    const month = entitySheet.getRange('N6').getValue();
    const entityIndex = entitySheet.getRange('J7').getValue();
    const exportParams = {
        method:"GET",
        headers:{Authorization:"Bearer "+authorizationToken},
        muteHttpExceptions:true
    };
    const entityOk = entitySheet.getRange('K26').getValue();
    var success;
    var entityPDFFileName = "";
    if ( entityOk ) {
        entityPDFFileName = "Entity_OK_"+year+"_"+month+"_"+entityIndex+".pdf";
    }
    else {
        entityPDFFileName = "Entity_"+year+"_"+month+"_"+entityIndex+".pdf";
    }
    if ( !driveFileExists(entitysStorageFolderOnGDrive,entityPDFFileName) ) {
        var entityPDFContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, exportParams).getBlob().setName(entityPDFFileName);
        entitysStorageFolderOnGDrive.createFile(entityPDFFileName, entityPDFContent, MimeType.PDF);
        success = true;
    }
    else {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Expected is expected in your scenario. I believe this is not a real issue, as in, the end user maybe misunderstood something and is lying to you(not on purpose). However, Make sure you have no triggers on the end user's spreadsheet.

Comment: End user just takes the spreadsheet as I developed it, and simply uses it as is. I set up an installable trigger in the apps script associated to the sheet, but all this has seen its ownership transferred to the end user, right?
My expectation is that, when the end user uses the sheet, the sheet's behavior is exactly the same as for me, ie creating files in end user's drive with end user's ownership, as he is now the only owner of the spreadsheet/apps script.
Am I wrong?

Comment: Installable triggers runs under the authority of the user who created  the trigger. Who created the trigger?

Comment: First, I would like to correctly understand your question. So, I would like to confirm your situation. 1. About `So, when work was finalized, I changed the ownership of my spreadsheet to the "final" owner, and this owner accepted the ownership.`, in this case, how do you run this? From your question, I cannot find the method for transferring the ownership and accepting the ownership. 2. About `this owner accepted the ownership`, after this, when you check the owner of the Spreadsheet, who is the owner?

Comment: @Tanaike When sharing a google sheet, you have the option to "Transfer ownership". By doing this, the transfer is pending and an email is sent to the "new owner". When the new user has accepted the ownership transfer, then the transfer is effective and the spreadsheet does belong to the new owner.
When I check who is the owner, this is indeed the "new" owner, the final user, the guy I did the transfer into.

Comment: @TheMaster, do you mean an installable trigger which has been installed on a spreadsheet does not follow the ownership transfer? Which means everything is belonging to the new owner except the trigger? If so, why doesn't it simply remove trigger?
BTW, if the new user installs a trigger by himself, with same callback function, will it work?

Comment: Triggers have separate ownership and is associated with a Google account. It cannot be transferred. `if the new user installs a trigger by himself, with same callback function, will it work?` Yes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `When sharing a google sheet, you have the option to "Transfer ownership". By doing this, the transfer is pending and an email is sent to the "new owner".`, if you are manually processing this flow, in this case, I think that your trigger cannot be transferred. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.

Comment: For example, when you can make users run a script, I think that when this flow is processed by a script, your goal might be able to be achieved by one execution of the script. But, I'm not sure whether this approach might not be your expected answer. So, I propose it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installable triggers have separate ownership and is associated with a Google account. Installable triggers runs under the authority of the user, who created the trigger. It cannot be transferred.

The new user has to create a  new trigger.

Comment: Did it, and indeed file owner is now final user. But now PDF files only contain 4 bytes: the word "Blob".
Is there any reason for this? I must admit I'm a little bit puzzled with ownership behaviour, some conceptual points I must not have understood. Especially that we cannot deliver a turnkey solution, but final user has to dig in apps to reinstall its own triggers.
That's why I fear another pb which forbids script to have blob content dumpes in pdf file

Comment: @EmmanuelFranquemagne You can provide a "Menu" for the end user to create his/her own trigger. Also, new errors/ questions should be asked in a new post. Ask a new question about the blob with [mcve] please(PS: It is not related too this error)